# How to write this select statement?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

If I have `table1` contains `Name, col2, col3` and `table2` contains `Name, NickName and col6`.

I want to do select statement such I have a table like:

```
Name, NickName, col2, col3
```

where if `table1` has 3 rows the new table should have the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating to answer your question:

Try this:

```
WITH tbl2 AS (SELECT DISTINCT ON (Name) Name,Nickname FROM table2 ORDER BY Name)

SELECT tbl1.Name, tbl2.Nickname, tbl1.col2, tbl1.col3 FROM
table1 tbl1 INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.Name = tbl2.Name
```

Disclaimer: haven't tested this. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I think you mean `ON` instead of `WHERE`? Also, Imagine you have 1 row in `table1` and 4 rows in `table2`, so will get more than one row when the condition `table1.Name = table2.Name` is satisfied.

Comment: So how would you know which record to select from table2?! Do you just want the first match? This might cause interesting behavior.